# When is $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}$ equal to $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{df}{dt}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Under what circumstances are $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{df}{dt}$ equal?

I'm aware that in some cases one or the other limit may not exist (e.g. if $f(t) = sin(t)$ the limit of the derivative does not exist.)

More precisely, I'm interested in whether  the limits are equal if $f$ is monotonically increasing and smooth.

Comment: Surely they are equal if $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{f(t)}t$? This is a separable differential equation with general solution $f(t)=t+C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Define what you mean by 2 limit being equal.

Comment: Consider f(t) = e^-t. Then the limit of e^-t/t as t -> infinity is 0, and similiarly df/dt = -e^-t and the limit of df/dt = 0. This example shows a monotonically decreasing function (not increasing) that has the property you desire.

Comment: The differential equation doesn't give all the solutions as you don't need the equality to hold for every point, only in the limit.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I guess my question is more: if $f(t)$ is increasing and smooth, are the limits always equal?

Comment: If $\lim_{t \to \infty}f(t) = \infty$ than by the L'Hopital's rule it's true.

Comment: @GáborPálovics Thanks! That's very helpful!

Comment: @GáborPálovics The below answer is a counterexample, though.

Comment: The below answer includes a case where the limit of one of them does not exist. He is only interested in cases where the limits both exist.

Comment: It's a condition of the  L'Hopital rule that the derivative's limit should exist.
So if $\lim _{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists, then you have equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \pm \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f′(x)$ exists, then you have equality by L'Hopital’s rule.

Comment: Please use mathjax

Comment: In the most general form of L'Hôpital's rule, it is not needed that $f$ tends to $\infty$. It does not even need to have a limit. All you need is the existence of the limit of $f'$.

Answer (score 3):

[$f(x) = x + \sin(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%2B%20sin%28x%29) is monotone, as $f'(x) \geq 0\ $ for all $x.$

This function satisfies $\ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{t} = 1\ $ but $\ \lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{df}{dt}\ $ does not exist.

The question of: "when are they equal" is more interesting and difficult.

The above example of $f(x) = x + \sin(x)$ shows that, in general, we **do not** have:

$  \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{t} = c,\implies\ \lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{df}{dt}=c\ $.

The accepted answer is clever and tells us about the converse statement.